# What are examples covering the spectrum of possibilities of inflection types across languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, inflection, conjugation

I am currently looking at [Turkish adjective intensification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_grammar#Intensification) where they are formed by adding a letter in the *middle* of the word, according to some rules (after first consonant + vowel):

> - siyah ("black") → si**m**siyah ("pitch black")
> - güzel ("pretty") → gü**p**güzel ("very pretty")
> - temiz ("clean") → te**r**temiz ("clean as a pin")
> - katı ("hard") → ka**s**katı ("hard as a rock")

I know in [Sanskrit](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/learning-sanskrit-combination-7-1/434), they have suffixes where the end of the base word is modified, and the beginning of the suffix is modified, when they are joined:

> राजन् (rājan) + तत्र (tatra) = राजंस्तत्र or राजँस्तत्र (rāja**ṁs**tatra or rāja**m̐s**tatra)

In Spanish, you also have removing ends of the base word and adding suffixes.

But I don't have enough knowledge to curate some examples from other languages that break this mold even more, and do things beyond that.

I am searching for examples from any language to demonstrate that these are also perhaps possibilities:

1. moon + bar = moo**md**ar (change end of prefix and beginning of suffix)
2. moon + adar = **ad**moon**ar** (the modifier word wraps the original word)
3. moon + bar = **sw**oonbar (combining with "suffix" also adds some wrapping element)
4. mind + barad = **min**bar**d**ad (intermingle parts)
5. ???

What is the spectrum of inflection combinations/cases you need to understand in order to build a software tool to unpack words into their components? That's basically where I'm coming from.

Comment: In any event, you have to go language by language and not expect to find one thing that fits all of them....

Comment: Here's a [freshman homework problem about Turkish intensive reduplication](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/TurkishReduplication.pdf). As it turns out the (very surprising) solution is misleading, since a couple of the allomorphs are very rare and don't follow the phonological rule.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the word "inflection" in an unusual way since *güpgüzel* in Turkish is an example of "derivation", so I presume you don't mean the old-fashoned derivation / inflection difference, instead you just mean "morphology". Since in your schematic example at the bottom you don't talk about what this means, I take it that you are interested in form, not meaning. One cannot avoid consideration of meaning, but it is not too hard to find resources that focus on form. Some basic resources are Katamba *Morphology* (Palgrave), Lieber *Introducing morphology* (CUP), Matthews *Morphology* (Cambridge), Haspelmath *Understanding morphology* (Hodder) or Aronoff & Fudeman *What is morphology* (Wiley). This should provide you with a 101-style understanding of word-formation, which would then lead to more specific questions.

For example, the Turkish process that you cite is an example of reduplication, of the subtype prefixing partial reduplication. It further exemplifies a feature of reduplication, that of fixed segmentalism. If this fascinates you, you could then take up a more extensive study of reduplication, because there are very many different kinds of reduplication, and some languages have dozens of reduplication patterns for different purposes (Lushootseed does, for example).

The domain that you seem to be interested in is heavily biased in favor of phonological processes, where a particular morphological category sets off phonological rules, which may have the appearance of morpheme-specificity. Ultimately, this means getting a grip on the technology of phonological analysis.